# How to create a script that can edit a plist in OSX

Tags: macos, scripting

So I am constantly manually modifying plists on a day-to-day basis (I'm on OSX 10.9), and I decided to create a script that will do this automatically for me.

After some more research, I found I could create a .command file to execute commands on a double clickable file.

Now, I'm not sure how I want to do the checking of a plist for a string, and if it's found, how to replace it.  Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two relevant commands here: `defaults` and `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`. `defaults` is really set up for managing preference settings, while `PlistBuddy` is a more general plist tool. For instance, to check and set your dock orientation (which side of the screen it appears on), you could use:

```
oldOrientation=$(defaults read com.apple.dock orientation)
defaults write com.apple.dock orientation "$newOrientation"
```

vs. the `PlistBuddy` version:

```
oldOrientation=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :orientation" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :orientation '$newOrientation'" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

As this example shows, `PlistBuddy`'s syntax is clumsier and more verbose... but it's also far more powerful if you're trying to do something nontrivial.

- While `defaults` can be given the full path to plist files that aren't in your ~/Library/Preferences folder, it *always* appends ".plist" to the filename, so if you're working with a file that doesn't have that extension, `defaults` is out.
- `PlistBuddy` can easily drill down into arrays and dictionaries within the plist file; for example, to get the URL for the first permanent entry in the right side of your dock, you'd just refer to `:persistent-others:0:tile-data:file-data:_CFURLString`. (Note that arrays are 0-indexed, so `:persistent-others:0` is the first element, `:persistent-others:1` is the second, etc). Something like this:

  ```
  fileURL=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :persistent-others:0:tile-data:file-data:_CFURLString" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist)
  ```

  ...and that's not really something `defaults` can do.